# What is the complement to "tracker"?

Tags: single-word-requests

What is the best word for describing a thing 'to be tracked'? In the vein of employer is to employee as tracker is to ...? I'm using it to refer to the proxy used by a feature tracking algorithm.

Comment: *Prey,* perhaps. What's the context?

Comment: I'm using it to refer to the proxy used by a feature tracking algorithm.

Comment: The rabbit. Like the mechanical target at dog races.

Comment: _tracked_ might work best. Hunter and hunted, tracker and tracked.

Comment: *Target* might work, except for the hostile implications, and *objective* **approaches** the point as well.

Comment: There's plenty of support for the word "trackee," though in the context of proxies and algorithms, I don't think it's the best choice.

Comment: I don't think there's a useful English term for OP's context. It's the sort of concept that might seem useful in a programming context involving automated delivery tracking systems (where a credible terms might be *item, package, deliverable*), but that would be useless if the thing being tracked was, say, a blue whale tagged by a wildlife research project. As it stands, the question seems Too Broad to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Quarry** [MW](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/quarry)

Very similar to Prey, but without the implication that you are going to eat the object of pursuit.

Edit: Poor reading comprehension on my part.  I wouldn't use this to describe the target of an algorithm, but I'll leave it up as an answer to the first half of the question.

I would use an business acronym for this purpose, "KPI" (Key-Performance-Indicator).  It's not a single word, but it does mean more or less exactly what you appear to be looking for. [Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Performance_indicator)

Comment: I quite like the idea of using *quarry* figuratively with an algorithm, though I'm sure it would cease to delight me and begin to make me shudder if such a figurative use became commonplace.

Comment: Every time I utilize delightful language in my business setting while attempting to avoid biztalk, I end up in HR.

Comment: Alas. Did they make you use *utilize* there, or has it become ingrained? ;)